# Looping through rows within a procedure in order to lessen client side and network activity

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

We are creating a database to store test data for our products during manufacture, and I am having difficulty in designing the API that will interact with the data.  We have developed the schema per a set of requirements we developed.  The schema is not the focus of this post.

My question deals with the correct and most efficient way of querying a specific type of data from the DB.

The schema consists of:

1. configurations table (stores information about specific products that can be manufactured, i.e. widget A, thingie B)
2. product family table (stores information about product families that we sell, i.e. widgets, thingies)
3. required tests (contains all tests for all families of product, i.e. Widget A Size, Thingie B Weight)
4. a table of test parameter pass/fail criteria (criteria for each product to pass manufacture, i.e. Widget A Max Size, Thingie B Weight Range).  Criteria may change over time and the newest entry is the active one.
5. a table of serial numbers (includes serial number and the associated configuration, i.e. 123 is a Widget A, 456 is a Thingie B)
6. a table to store the test results (i.e. Serial Number 123's Size is 12", Serial Number 456 Weight is 1.5lbs).  Note a test result may not exist yet OR multi tests may have be run.  The newest one is the active one.

There are primary keys and relationships that maintain data integrity, etc, etc.

My question is in regards to generating a summary of test results for a specific serial number.  I can do this on the client side with large number queries.  For example:

1. Find configuration and family for the serial number (using tables 1 and 5).
2. In a single query, return all of the tests required for that family (from table 3).
3. Loop through each row (test) from #2 and find the most current pass fail criteria from table 4.
4. Loop through each row (test) from #2 and find the most current result (if it exists).
5. Determine if that test passes and, thus, if the serial number passes all tests.

My question is two fold.  One, am I missing a more complex SQL query that lessens the load on the client side?  Two, I would like to push this into a stored procedure in order to expose a straightforward API to the DB that can be managed server side.  I am having trouble finding the correct syntax to loop though query results within a procedure WHILE creating dynamic queries within the procedure given the results from the original query.  Can this be done?

I can post more detailed information on the schema as the discussion continues.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "The schema is not the focus of this post". It should be. You're asking how to query something efficiently, and that starts with the schema. Posting the structure with expected results will help answer your question. Without these details it's all conjecture.